# How to access ubuntu server 16.04 sever's files from windows 10 PC?

Tags: networking, server, permissions, apache2, samba

I recently installed ubuntu 16.04 on a machine I built, hoping that it'd serve my home for file sharing, media server and probably for VPN. I have installed Samba and the LAMP server. I also have installed phpmyadmin. Then I have created some folders under 'home' and shared it over my home-network.

Now, when I try to access them from my windows PCs it won't let me to, and asks a username and password every time. I didn't know initially what credentials to provide, and was providing those which I used to set up the ubuntu server. I was not being granted access. After scouring the internet for 3 straight days, I still can't come up with a solution. I tried adding users with passwords in Samba, and tried logging in with those credentials, but with no avail. I tried editing the samba configuration file as suggested in many ubuntu Q&As, but it differs largely from what described in the pages, and I couldn't even find many of the parameters. The little bit of tweaks that I made in the configuration file couldn't help alleviate the problem. 
Please help me out with it. I am really into it for the past three days and am starting to lose my patience now.

A screen shot of the global settings:

[image]

The authentication settings:

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful, if we could see your smb.conf

Comment: Please post your smb.conf, or just the global settings, in a code block in your question.

Comment: I have included the global settings in a screenshot in my question. Please do have a look.

Comment: Have a look, please.

Comment: Had a similar problem. I finally managed to connect my Windows 10 client to my Ubuntu 16 server the following way: http://askubuntu.com/questions/820549/ubuntu-16-samba-server-with-windows-10-client-tutorial-howto/820550#820550

Answer (score 0):

sudo passwd -a username and set your password for your given username, use it when Windows asks for the name and password.

Comment: I have tried that. It didn't help.

Comment: in user did you use your user name, have you set permissions for folders to be given share access. in GUI its usually a right click affair, in server without GUI I use Webadmin to do the same.

Comment: I think I added a samba username and password, not like what you suggested. 

sudo smbpasswd -a username. 

And yes, I do have set permissions for folders to be accessed.

Comment: Try smbpasswd samba_user and then create new password to see if this issue goes away.

Comment: I did add a samba user with a password. with this smbpasswd -a username. I tried logging in with those credentials, but it didn't help. :-(